# how do I see the outcomes of each function line In Python

Tags: python, debugging

I'm trying to figure out how to view the effects of each line in python code since I'm reading other's code and want to know how each line in python works. For example, I have the following code and would like to check what each line of this code produces.

could someone help me how to accomplish this?

**Code**

```
def ValidParentheses(s):
    stack = []
    for i in s:
        if i == '(':
            stack.append(i)
        elif i == ')':
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            else:
                stack.pop()
    if len(stack) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

s = '())'
print(ValidParentheses(s))
```

result: False

Comment: here, <http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit> this will help

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understood your goal right, but have you considered running it in a debugger?

Comment: You could also just add `print(stack)` after each line that updates `stack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do that in 2 ways:

1. You can add simple `print` to `i` and `stack` to see where they are in each loop iteration, for example:

```
def ValidParentheses(s):
    stack = []
    for i in s:
        print(f'{i=} {stack=}')         # Just added this line
        if i == '(':
            stack.append(i)
        elif i == ')':
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return False
            else:
                stack.pop()
    if len(stack) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

s = '())'
print(ValidParentheses(s))
```

and the output will be:

```
i='(' stack=[]
i=')' stack=['(']
i=')' stack=[]
False
```

2. you can use a debugger, and multiple breakpoints to stop whenever you want and see what each variable is holding at that current time. You can use one that is on Pycharm, it is very recommended, or any other IDE that works with python. Just write the IDE name and "debugger" and youtube and you will see a lot of tutorials.